# A road map to learning Flex for dummies

Tags: apache-flex, ide

I need to familiarize myself with this technology. My problem is that Google is swamp with results for tutorials.  Where should I start?
What development environment should I use assuming this is only for learning purposes and I don't want at the moment to buy any expensive software?
What tools should I use?
Any road maps for dummies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really think that "learning Flex" is a mistake. Focusing up on core Actionscript 3 skills is essential to long term success with the Flex framework. You will find that you rapidly hit a wall where "knowing Flex" without the underlying language core will be an extreme disadvantage. If you have prior experience with a statically typed language, the AS3 shouldn't be difficult. All of Flex is written in AS3, and analyzing the underlying codebase is the best way I have found to learn the framework.

[Essential Actionscript 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) is the best place to start down that path.

Comment: Well, to become effective with _any_ language, you need to learn the language as well as the libraries/frameworks available, but this is a good reminder none the less.

Comment: +1 So I have to start with AS3? am I correct?

Comment: By all means play around with Flex, *all* of Flex is written in AS3, so to gain a proper working knowledge you need to understand the language. The default Flex components are great, but the real power comes when you can extend and create your own.

Answer (score 3):

Flex Builder has a 60 day free trial so that should be enough time to get you started.  After that you can use the [Open Source Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/flex).  To learn Flex you can check out [First Steps in Flex](http://www.firststepsinflex.com) which is a short book  Bruce Eckel and I co-authored.  We have also posted [some screencasts](http://www.firststepsinflex.com/#chapters) that walk through the code examples in the book.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe's ["Flex in a Week" video training](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/) is a great place to start learning.

Answer (score 1):

[Flex for dummies...](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470277920)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VMOiSL-uL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VMOiSL-uL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

But seriously figure out a simple flex application you want make and make it. That is the best tutorial. Then when you get stuck you will have a specific problem you are looking to solve. The myriad of tutorials on Google will then begin to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Features:Interface) is a decent free IDE which works with the free Flex SDK (free commandline compiler from Adobe)

Answer (score 1):

There is a series from O'Reilly (insideria.com) called LFFS - Learn Flex from Scratch - that is pretty good. There are currently 12 lessons - each building on the previous.

http://www.insideria.com/2008/02/lffs1-meet-the-authors-meet-fl.html

Answer (score 0):

I like the book [Flex 3 from the Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321529189). After you have a little bit of context for Flex, check out the [Flex Examples blog](http://blog.flexexamples.com/).